# Evaluate the path integral of $f(x, y) = y$ over the graph of the semicircle $y = \sqrt{1-x^2}, -1 \leq x \leq 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the path integral of $f(x, y) = y$ over the graph of the semicircle $y = \sqrt{1-x^2}, -1 \leq x \leq 1$

Solution attempt:

$f(x, y) = y$, along $y = \sqrt{1-x^2}, -1 \leq x \leq 1$

$\vec{r}(t) = (t, \sqrt{1-t^2}), -1 \leq t \leq 1$

$\vec{r}'(t) = (1, \frac{-2t}{2\sqrt{1-t^2}}) = (1, \frac{-t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}})$

$||\vec{r}'(t)|| = \sqrt{1+\frac{t^2}{1-t^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$

Show $\int f(x, y) dt = \int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{1-t^2}||\vec{r}'(t)|| dt = \int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{1-t^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} dt = 1+1 = 2$

therefore the value of the required path integral is 2

is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also parameterise the curve $x=cost$, $y=sint$

$$r'(t) = <-sint,cost>$$

$$||r'(t)|| = 1$$

$$F = sin t$$

$$I = \int_{0}^{\pi} sint dt = -cost|_{0}^{\pi} = 2$$

Comment: (+1) for typing faster than I